# Disable Holidays from a UIPickerView on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

How can I disable specific dates from a `UIPickerView` that's `.datePickerMode` has been set to `UIDatePickerModeDate`? I need to disable holidays and weekends.

Comment: You need to create your own UIDatePicker replacement, using a standard UIPickerView, and an NSCalendar to get the dates. Shouldn't be too hard.